# jquery getting the text writed in the input type text

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking for a solution but I haven't got lucky.

if I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="x" id="x" value="123"/>
```

and I have this in jquery.

```
$('#x').val()
```

it returns me -> 123 thats correct.

But if I want to edit that field firstly with 123 as the default value and I re-write to 321 and I make the same command in Jquery, im still having 123 instead of 321.

So the question is how can I get what I have written in the type text input.

Thanks you all!

Here my html code:

```
<input type="text" name="hotel_name" id="edit_hotel_name" class="edit_hotel_name w100p"     value="<?php echo $hotel['hotel_name'];?>"/>
```

Here my jquery dialog processor:

```
$("#dialog_hotel_content_edit_" + id_hotel).removeClass("hidden").dialog({
      dialogClass: "no-close",
      title: "Editar Hotel",
      height: "auto", 
      width: "auto",
      open: function(){
                get_corporations();
                get_zones($("#edit_state_id").val());
            }, 
      buttons: [{
          text: "Editar",
          click: function() {
                hotel_name = $(".edit_hotel_name").val()
                alert(hotel_name);
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

The task here is to edit some information through a dialog, so the information comes by the value attribute and then when I click the "Editar" button it gets the information written in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy peasy in jQuery.  Just use the `.on('input'` function

```
$('#x').on('input', function() {
    //do whatever you need to in here
});
```

example on how to use this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/sa59D/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**keyup()**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or **[keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)** event to get the new value of your input after typing:

```
$('#x').keyup(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
}).keyup();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UQ4rh/)**

Comment: i believe , uder any event of `input` elem it will give the new value, so keyup is not the only option

Comment: Yes, I just give OP some options to choose from since I don't know which way he prefer though.

Comment: This can be choppy if a user presses and holds down a key.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6HmxM/4/)**

```
$("#boxx").keypress(function() {
   var $this= $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       $("div").text($this.val());
    }, 0);
});
```