# Double Drop-Down Menu with HTML and JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently setup a double drop-down menu following this example:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut183.shtml

I needed the drop-down menu options to run a certain function, and someone helped me with this code below.

Is there anyway I can implement the double drop down to the below JSFiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/v6wRY/4/

HTML:

```
 <select>
  <option value="func1">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="func2">Candy</option>
  <option value="func3">Taffy</option>

</select>
<div></div>
```

And the JS:

```
var functions = {
    func1: function(){console.log("func1 called")},
    func2: function(){console.log("func2 called")},
    func3: function(){console.log("func3 called")},
}

$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var selected = $( "select option:selected" );
    functions[selected.val()]();
  })
  .change();
```

Comment: If you need to run the function right when the menu option is selected, may I suggest you take a look at [some of these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119318/jquery-getting-the-text-writed-in-the-input-type-text/22119684#22119684) to initiate the function, and use jQuery's [.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to determine what is in the box?

Comment: I would rather have a button be pushed before the function runs, but whichever way works for me. I will take a look.

Comment: Here is a complete example which create drop down if you select the option from first http://coursesweb.net/javascript/multiple-select-dropdown-list-javascript_t

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is either impossible or terribly difficult to make a double drop down by way of a select with options. I recommend using an unordered list format instead, depending on what exactly you need it for you can format it in such a way that still works with what you're doing.